# What does the "close" suggestions by 2k-3k users in the low quality review queue mean?

Tags: support, review

I was drawn to this LQ review queue

https://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/1944174

where 7 reviewers chose the option "close", while 3 others chose "looks ok". The post is not closed though: if I understand correctly, 3 of the 7 reviews who chose the "close" option has reps 2k-3k and thus cannot cast a close vote.

This makes me wonder, what is the effect of "close" chose by those users? It seems that it never settle the review: does it raise an automatic flag for the moderators to review, as in the case for "[recommend deletion](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33537/why-is-an-answer-not-deleted-even-when-all-reviewers-recommend-deletion)"?

Comment: In general I think the number of upvotes a post has comes into the calculation.  I'll try to find a reference.  Apparently the review completed without closing the post (which had zero votes of up or down).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer in the FAQ post "[What are the review queues, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161390)" ([current revision](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/161391/55) says:

> If you haven't earned the close privilege, you'll be offered a **Recommend Close** option instead - this carries no vote on its own, but puts the question in the Close Votes queue for privileged users to vote to close (see "Close Votes" below).

---

Also related:

- [How can a low quality post can get more than 15 or 20 reviewers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356261)
- [Low Quality review queue erroneously showing "Close" instead of "Recommended Close"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208221)